# How to import GUN SEA with Deno Fresh?

Tags: deno, gun, gundb, freshjs

The first attempt to import GUN from Fresh was to add the gun library from esm to `import_map.json`, where it correctly works in simple examples of using GUN.

```json
{
  "imports": {
    ...
    "gun": "https://esm.sh/gun@0.2020.1237",
  }
}
```

But the problem occurred when I wanted to import additionally `gun/sea`,
After importing `import Sea from "gun/sea";`.

I got this error:

`error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Dynamic require of "./lib/text-encoding" is not supported`

On GitHub I read to import `gun/lib/mobile` before importing SEA when such a problem occurs.
But this brings an additional problem:

`error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

I checked the `gun/lib/mobile` file and it literally contains a few lines of global variables:

```js
import Buffer from "buffer";
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from "text-encoding";
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || Buffer.Buffer;
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

Is there any chance to make SEA work on Fresh?

Comment: this looks like either a bug with ESM's conversion of the code or an issue with the Gun sources; I suggest creating an issue to at https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/new; alternatively you can try Deno's unstable support for "npm:" prefixed modules (i.e. try `import GUN from "npm:gun";`)

Answer (score 0):

Add following line inside imports in `import_map.json` file:

```
"@gun": "https://esm.sh/gun@0.2020.1237"
```

Then use this import statement to import GUN in any route/component:

```
import GUN from "@gun"
```

Usage (from GUN documentation):

```
const gun = GUN();

gun.get('mark').put({
  name: "Mark",
  email: "mark@gun.eco",
});

gun.get('mark').on((data, key) => {
  console.log("realtime updates:", data);
});

setInterval(() => { gun.get('mark').get('live').put(Math.random()) }, 9);
```